# iOS App rejection - 18.2

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

My first app just got rejected and I am a bit confused :S

It is an app that allows the user to upload images to a gallery. I already though of this guideline and introduced a moderation panel so the admin individually accepts or rejects images that should or should not be published.

This is what they told me:

> ### 18.2: Apps that contain user generated content that is frequently pornographic (e.g. "Chat Roulette" Apps) will be rejected
>
> 18.2
>
> We found your app enables the display of user-generated content which may become sexually explicit. Therefore we ask that you put the following precautions in place, to ensure your app remains in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> - Require that your users agree to terms (EULA) and these terms must be clear that there's no tolerance for objectionable content
> - Users need a way to flag or report objectionable content and users generating this content
> - Developer needs a method for ejecting users who violate the terms of the EULA

Where do I go from here? As I said, i had all implemented and it is impossible for a "pornographic" image to appear on my app as someone has to check every image before they appear.

About the EULA, does it has to be a `UIAlertView` asking the user to accept or do I have to edit the EULA at iTunes Connect so it fits my purpose?

Also, do moderators answer when i ask a question in the resolution center?

Comment: Moderators do answer pretty quickly and they even call and try to solve your problems directly. About the EULA I cant give you any information, but hope someone else can.

Comment: When you uploaded your app to the App store for review did you tell them no image would appear before it gets moderated? Are these images public facing or private? As far as Apple are aware someone could take a random picture and upload it using your app and anything could happen, a moderator may not review the image correctly if at all. Apps that upload images are quite hard to get through because anything could be uploaded whether it's moderator or not and Apple don't like there devices to be used for this purpose.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming, it is about Apple App Store approval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like this rejection can be handled via a response rather than a code change. Let them know that you're images are all adjudicated, that you do have methods for detecting (you adjudicate the images after all) and ejecting users. Chances are this will be all they'll need to hear and you can resubmit your app.

`UIAlertView` for terms will most likely not have enough room to `make it clear` there's no tolerance for objectionable content - use a modal ViewController that displays your terms upon first use/registration and require the users to click an "Accept" button in order to dismiss it.

Comment: The images need to not only be "adjudicated" but need to be reviewed **prior** to availability. This somewhat because Apple is relying on your staff to ensure parental controls are enforced and that a "Chat Roulette" does not occur without your knowledge.

Comment: @Zaph - excellent point, that is actually what I was intending but my wording missed the point.

Comment: So do I speak to the reviewer via de Resolution Center? I did ask them a couple of questions and they did not answer (this was 15 hours ago). Is that resolution center made to 'ask questions to the reviewer'? Please bear in mind this is my first app. I have never encounter something like this before :/. Thanks again :)

Comment: I would appeal the app rejection here - https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/?topic=appeal. In the meantime, I'd make sure that you implement that `make it clear` part of your terms and conditions that users must agree to in case they still nail you for that. Then you can upload your new binary and try again.

Comment: @Adam - I think you are right. Do appeals take long to processed? I heard they may last for weeks. In that case probably is better to go and edit your project instead of being there waiting to tell you that you have to resubmit and loose so much time.

Comment: @alvarolopez - appeal it so the record of the appeal is in the system. They may also point out during your appeal if you are likely to get through or not even after you make your modifications to your terms. Your appeal will be based on a single rule (18.2) so it shouldn't take that long (my guess is that it would max out at a week and most likely be two-three days).